# Data is being entered twice when cross domain web service is fired

Tags: cross-domain, jsonp

I have created a .net web service and when i try to call a method that saves the data in the database, the request is fired twice. I use net profiler to check if two requests are made to the server but only one request is made to server. I fail to understand why data is being entered twice in the database.I am using jsonp method to call the cross domain site

I just found something interesting. I have two servers. When i host the web service on one and call the web service using cross domaining, the data is entered once whereas on the other the data is entered twice. Do we need to take care of some IIS settings too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyi all, i just converted my project to visual studio 2010 and then installed it on the server. Everything is running perfectly now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, if there aren't two requests being made then there are almost certainly two calls to the Save() method (or whatever it is called), being fired from the web service end point. But there maybe dupliacte data somewhere too.

Here are  a couple of things to check:

- What data is actually being
  transferred? Have you checked this
  using a tool like Charles?
- Is the data being passed to your Save() method the same as the data being passed to the web service?
- How is the data being written to the database? Is there duplicate SQL somewhere?

Comment: I don not think there should be a problem with the save method as if if directly call the webservice, the data is saved only once.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to check how many times the save method is being called? Either this is being called twice, the save method is writing the data twice, or twice the amount of data is being passed to be saved. Also check the logs to see what is being requested.

Comment: Heyi i did check the data that is being sent too. The data looks ok. If i run the same code on my local machine the data is saved once. But if i upload the web service on the production and then request to save, it gets saved twice.

Comment: I just found something interesting. I have two servers. When i host the web service on one and call the web service using cross domaining, the data is entered once whereas on the other the data is entered twice. Do we need to take care of some IIS settings too?